# Will creating a variable with an existing variable's name but with 'old' before it create a copy of the existing variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

For example, I have a variable called exampleVariable and it holds integers. It contains a value of 1. Will typing 'Var oldExampleVariable : Int' instantly create a variable called oldExampleVariable with a value of 1? If so, will typing 'exampleVariable = oldExampleVariable' make one of them have a value of 2? And if so for that, which one will have a value of 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it will do neither of those things. I don't know where you learned this, but it is not the behaviour of Swift.

In Swift, variable's values are *completely* independent. And `=` means to make the variable on the left hold the value on the right.

When you create a new variable by adding an `old` prefix to an existing variable name:

```
var exampleVariable = 1
var oldExampleVariable: Int
```

It just creates another variable called `oldExampleVariable` which is completely independent and has not been initialised.

If you do something like this:

```
oldExampleVariable = exampleVariable
```

`oldExampleVariable` is now `1`, but it is still independent. It just so happens to have the same value as `exampleVariable`.